# Django no pasa los datos del formulario a la base de datos

Tags: django, django-forms

Soy nueva en Django y estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación que cree un beneficiario en la base de datos mysql, cuando le doy guardar no sale ningun error y me redirecciona al template de exito tal como esta en la vista, pero cuando voy a buscar el registro en la base de datos no aparece nada, y si trato de que me muestre los errores con form.errors tampoco me muestra nada, y si trato de recuperar los datos con print(request.POST) tampoco, es como si desapareciera los datos, por favor alguna sugerencia, a continuación les muestro mi codigo:

primero la conexión con la base de datos:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'axypruebas',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '3306',
        }
    }
```

El models:

```
class Beneficiario(models.Model):
     benef_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
     benef_nombres = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     benef_apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**el form**

```
class formFichaReg(ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for form in self.visible_fields():
    form.field.widget.attrs.update({'autocomplete': 'off'})
        class Meta:
            model = Beneficiario
            fields = '__all__'
            labels = {
                      'benef_id' : 'identificacion',
                      'benef_nombres' : 'Nombres',
                      'benef_apellidos': 'Apellidos'
                      }
```

**La vista**

```
class fichaSocReg(CreateView): 
        model=Beneficiario
        form_class = formFichaReg
        template_name = 'plantillas/adminFicha.html' 
    
    def post(self, request, ):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        # <process form cleaned data>
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('success') )
```

**y el template**

```
 <form action="{% url 'success' %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <strong>Notificación: </strong> {{ form.errors}}
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria- 
             label="Close"></button>
            <P></P>
   </div>
          
          <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="form-check col-xs-12 col-md-4 mb-3">
              <label>
                Tipo de Información
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check col-xs-12 col-md-4 mb-3">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="rRegNuevo" 
              checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="rRegNuevo">
                Registro Inicial
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check col-xs-12 col-md-4 mb-3">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="rActuli">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="rActuali">
                Actualización
              </label>
            </div>
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <div class="row">
             
                <label for="{{ field.name }}" class="form-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
                {{ field }}
              
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
    
          </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="row mb-3 justify-content-center">
    
    
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 mb-3">
        <div class="row  mx-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Guardar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def post(self, request, ):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
    # <process form cleaned data>
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('success') )
```

El problema es que no estas guardando el formulario. La vista recibe el formulario verifica que es valido **if form.is_valid():**, pero no lo estas guardando (puedes llamar al **form.save()**)

Lo cambias por algo como:

**1.**

```
def post(self, request, ):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        # <process form cleaned data>
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('success') )
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, ya lo hice así pero aun no funciona, parece que me estaba redireccionando a la pagina de exito con la direccion que le di en el action del form y no desde la vista, ya le quite esa direccion y guarde el form como me dijiste y ahora me sale este error: The view plantillas.views.fichaSocReg didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. O sea que no esta retornando un objeto HttpResponse.  Alguna sugerencia??

Comment: @NATALIAMENDIETAMARIN ya lo arreglaste.

Answer (score 0):

ya resolví el problema, era mas fácil de lo que pensé, resulta que con la vista genérica creacte view no es necesario sobreescribir el metodo post, simplemente se le envían los parámetros establecidos en la vista, al final mi vista quedó así:

```
'class fichaSocReg(CreateView): 
    model=Beneficiario
    form_class = formFichaReg
    template_name = 'plantillas/adminFicha.html' 
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success')',
```

y también tuve que quitar la dirección que le había puesto en el action del form, en su lugar le puse una almohadilla, y ya me funciona, muchas gracias por su ayuda.